# Using @ConditionalOnMissingBean on class is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My code:

```java
@RestController
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = {"testController"})
@RequestMapping("/a")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/b")
    private String b() {
        return "1";
    }
}
```

In this case, I want to register a bean with name "testController" when the context is not having this bean. But it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

[according documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html) that is not supposed to work at all:

> The condition can only match the bean definitions that have been
> processed by the application context so far and, as such, it is
> strongly recommended to use this condition on auto-configuration
> classes only. If a candidate bean may be created by another
> auto-configuration, make sure that the one using this condition runs
> after.

you are misusing `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`